# How to extend Node classes for abstraction purposes within Cypress?

Tags: node.js, inheritance, cypress

**Goal**: Create a URL abstraction for our specific product by extending Node's URL class within a Cypress project.

**Problem**: Cypress executes everything within a browser context, so you can only use node modules in the plugins file which executes within a Node environment. However, I don't really need to *execute* anything, I just want to extend the available Node objects so I don't have to reimplement these abstractions myself.

I get the following error in Cypress when I set the `baseUrl` to `new ProductURL().toString()`:

[image]

Code:

```js
import { URL } from 'url';

export class ProductURL extends URL {
    static readonly DEFAULT_URL: string = "https://example.com";
    static readonly DEFAULT_AUTH: BasicAuthCredentials = {
        username: Cypress.env('BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME'),
        password: Cypress.env('BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD')
    }

    private domain: string;
    private subdomain: string;

    constructor() {
        super(ProductURL.DEFAULT_URL);
        this.setAuth(ProductURL.DEFAULT_AUTH);
    }

    public getDomain(): string {
        return this.domain;
    }

    public getSubdomain(): string {
        return this.subdomain;
    }

    public setPort(port: number) {
        this.port = String(port);
    }

    public setProtocol(protocol: Protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public setAuth(auth: BasicAuthCredentials | null) {
        this.username = auth ? auth.username : '';
        this.password = auth ? auth.password : '';
    }
}

export enum Protocol {
    HTTP = "http",
    HTTPS = "https"
}

export type BasicAuthCredentials = {
    username: string;
    password: string;
};
```

**Question**: How can I extend Node classes for abstraction purposes within Cypress context?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

It was creating a circular dependency because the `URL` class was already loaded, so the import statement:

`import { URL } from 'url'`

was unnecessary.